# Handling Memory Allocation and Pointers in Electron between Node.js and C++ DLL

Tags: c++, node.js, dll, electron, ffi

I'm developing an Electron application that requires interfacing with a C++ DLL to manage USB devices. Recently, based on recommendations and issues encountered with node-ffi-napi ([Issue #238](https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/238)), I transitioned to using koffi, a different FFI library designed to facilitate calling C functions from Node.js environments, including Electron.

The core functionality I'm trying to implement involves calling a C++ DLL function that allocates memory for an array of device structures using malloc and then returns a pointer to this array. Here's the C function prototype I'm dealing with:

```
/**
 * \brief This routine allows to get ST-LINK connected probe(s).
 * \param stLinkList  : Filled with the connected ST-LINK list and its default configurations.
 * \param shared      : Enable shared mode allowing connection of two or more instances to the same ST-LINK probe.
 * \return Number of the ST-LINK probes already exists.
 */
int getStLinkList(debugConnectParameters** stLinkList, int shared);
```

Attempting to interact with this function from my Electron app has presented some challenges, particularly around correctly allocating and passing a pointer to a pointer (debugConnectParameters**) that the DLL can use to allocate memory and return data.

Here's an approximation of my current approach in Node.js using koffi:

```
// Assuming 'lib' is the loaded DLL
const getStLinkList = lib.func('int', ['pointer', 'int']);

// Attempt to call getStLinkList
let stLinkListPtr = null; // Placeholder for a pointer to pointers
let shared = 0; // Example value for demonstration
let numberOfDevices = getStLinkList(stLinkListPtr, shared);
```

My questions are as follows:

How can I properly allocate a pointer to a pointer in an Electron app using koffi, allowing the DLL to allocate memory and return device data?
Once the DLL allocates memory and populates it with device structures, how do I access and iterate through this data in Node.js within an Electron context?
What are the best practices for managing memory allocated by a DLL in an Electron app, particularly to prevent memory leaks or access violations?
Any advice, code snippets, or resources on managing FFI interactions and memory allocation between Node.js (within Electron) and C++ DLLs would be incredibly helpful. I'm particularly interested in solutions or examples that address similar scenarios, taking into account the transition from node-ffi-napi to koffi.

I've been trying to interface an Electron app with a C++ DLL to manage USB devices. Specifically, I need to call a DLL function that allocates an array of structures for device data using malloc and returns a pointer to this array. I expected to properly allocate and pass a pointer to a pointer (debugConnectParameters**) to this function and then access the device data in Node.js.

What I Tried:

Switched from node-ffi-napi to koffi: Based on recommendations and an issue discussion, I moved to koffi for better Electron compatibility.
Pointer Allocation: Attempted to allocate a pointer to a pointer for the DLL function to allocate memory and fill with device data but struggled with correct implementation.
Function Call: Called the DLL function, expecting it to allocate memory for the device data array and to be able to iterate over it in Node.js.
Issues Encountered:

Unclear on how to correctly allocate and initialize a pointer to a pointer for the DLL to use.
Struggled with accessing and managing the memory allocated by the DLL post-function call.
Concerned about properly freeing the allocated memory to prevent memory leaks.
I'm seeking advice on handling pointer allocation and memory management for DLL interactions in an Electron context.

**Update**

- I wrote a DLL that wraps the original DLL. The new interface does not involve to pass a pointer to memory to the nodeJs side (which I thought it was the cause of the problem). This approach does not solve the problem.
- if I use the original DLL or this new wrapper-DLL from a C or CPP program, I get the correct behaviour from getStLinkList(); if I call either DLL via koffi, it returns 0 devices (instead of 1).

So for some reason, the function behaves incorrectly when called from koffi, either directly or via encapsulated wrapper.

I suspect that the problem is on koffi's side, but the fact that the function silently fails does not help (it does not give any error code).

Comment: The [documentation has an example](https://koffi.dev/output#opaque-type-example) of what you are trying to do but I could not figure out how to tie the `koffi.pointer` to a dynamically-sized array.

Comment: Hi Botje, thanks for your interest. I've read it but then it silently fails; if I pass a null pointer I get no errors and a 0 return value (but it should be 1). I'm now trying a different approach, based on writing a DLL that behaves in a way that koffi likes: I mean, no addresses of memory blocks created in the dll to pass to the node environment

Comment: Did you pass `null` or `[null]` ?